# How do I get a value asynchronously while not blocking the UI in PyGTK

Tags: python, user-interface, asynchronous, callback, pygtk

good people of the internet.

I'm writing a GUI application that needs to get the ID from an RFID card scanner attached to a Raspberry Pi. I'm using PyGTK in combination with Glade for the UI.

When the user clicks on the 'confirm' button, I want the app to scan for any cards (I have a function with a while True loop for this), but the user should also be able to press the 'cancel' and stop scanning for cards and reset some values.

I wanted to do this by starting the scanning function in another thread (or process) and, once scanned, make that process trigger a callback function to process the ID and run some other code, but I can't find any libraries that allow me to do this the way I imagined it could.

I've tried using Pool but calling `pool.apply_async(RFID.Get, callback = self.OnScan).get(timeout=15)` still blocks the IO.

I've done some async work in C# before this but am not at all completely familiar with how it's implemented in Python.

([The GUI I'm using.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibq8y.png))

I need to get this done A.S.A.P., so any help, hints or clues are appreciated. If I need to supply any code I will (although this project is not open-sourced, so I can't share everything).

Thank all of you in advance.